# How to render threaded comments using musatche templates?

Tags: javascript, mustache

I am trying to implement threaded comments for a blog-like system I am building. A comment might look like this (JavaScript):

```
{
    text: "whatever",
    author : "name"
    children: [ /* more comments*/ ]
}
```

Note that the child comments may have children themselves.

I have a mustache template which look like this:

```
{{#comments}}
    <li><div class='comment'>
        {{author}} wrote {{text}}
    </div></li>
{{/comments}}
```

Is there some way I can render threaded comments using this scheme?  Does mustache being logic-less mean that I cannot implement something like this using it?

FWIW I am using [mote.js](http://satchmorun.github.com/mote/) library for rendering the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great fit for partials. So your page template looks something like this:

```
...

<ul>
  {{# comments }}
    {{> comment }}
  {{/ comments }}
</ul>

...
```

And your comments partial looks something like this:

```
<li>
  <div class="comment">

    ... commentystuff

    <ul>
      {{# children }}
        {{> comment }}
      {{/ children }}
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

And since it looks like you're using JS, you can even conditionally hide that whole embedded UL if there are no child comments, just wrap it in a `{{# children.length }}` section:

```
<li>
  <div class="comment">

    ... commentystuff

    {{# children.length }}
      <ul>
        {{# children }}
          {{> comment }}
        {{/ children }}
      </ul>
    {{/ children.length }}
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Looks great! I will try this out and let you know. Thanks.